# Binding and unbinding of scroll event on window.

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-binding

I want binding and unbinding of scroll event on window. I have some code like this:

```
$("#test").bind('mousewheel', function(event) {
    $(window).unbind("scroll");
    // do something here
    $(window).bind("scroll");
});
```

The main motive behind is to disable window's scroll while performing some mouse-wheel activity and then enable it again afterwards. I am using jQuery 1.4.2 and can't update to latest jQuery due to some dependencies. I know latest versions of jQuery do provide functions like .on() and .off() which is suitable for my problem.

Is is possible to achieve same using jQuery 1.4.2?

Comment: But what, doesn't `unbind/bind` work??? Although for `bind`, you should pass a handler  http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Answer (score 1):

Yes ... it does work in jQuery 1.4.2

[Here](http://jsbin.com/rivuge/1/edit) you can see it working.

Just an add note: you can use `event.customName` to be able to control what events you are binding/unbinding. This way if you use `.unbind('mousewheel.myEvent')` you will preserve other possible scroll events.

Comment: $("#test").bind('mousewheel', function(event) 
{
  $(window).unbind("scroll");
  alert("wheel");$(window).bind("scroll",function(){$("#temp").append("scroll bind");});});    Similarly I have $(window).scroll(function(){alert("window Scroll");});  Here on mouseWheel Event window scroll is getting called by default.What I am expecting is whenever i am performing scrolling by mouse then the window scroll functionality shouldn't work and as soon as I am done with Mousewheel event my window scroll should be activated.. Plz help.

Comment: just curious... why do you want to stop the scroll functionality?

Comment: Its like rebinding the "scroll" event listener to the window after I am done with the actions performed on "mousewheel"event.

Comment: I have some task related to partial loading of data.And for 1 mousewheel event the scroll event is getting triggered 7-8 times and I don't want that.Hence I want mousewheel and window's scroll both mutually exclusive.

Comment: you will need to code that by hand ... there is no way to control how the event is triggered ... you just binds then ...